# Failed connection to mailserver

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send off a bulk email.. all BCC's.. ive tried everything i could find on google.. nothing seems to be working... ive checked my php.ini file as well and set it according to what i found on google...

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

I get the error in my title and a portion of my php file is below... any help would be much appreciated..

```
$to = "";
$header = "From:me@gmail.com\r\n";

//Compiling BCC list
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
    if($i == 0)
        $header .= $emailContacts[$i];
    else
        $header .= ",".$emailContacts[$i];
}

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header))
    echo "MAIL pass";
else
    echo "MAIL fail";
```

The error:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port"

Comment: On which platform are you working? Windows, Mac, Linux? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: im running on Windows 32-bit.. im not too sure how to run an smtp server...

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25)

Answer (score 1):

You need to either install an SMTP server on your computer, or use an external SMTP server. You could use Gmail, but they are fairly limited, I recommend using a service that specializes in this domain, such as [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com), [Mailjet](http://mailjet.com) or [Postmarkapp](http://postmarkapp.com)

As a great side benefit, these guys will make sure that you get maximum deliverability (don't end up in spam)

**Disclaimer**: I work for Mailjet