# CSS Alignment Issues with IE

Tags: php, html, css

[This page](http://nityaexports.com/Manufacturing.html) is showing different alignment in Internet Explorer to other browsers. Could you guide me in correcting it.

Comment: I would start validating the HTML you have a few errors http://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: Fixing Quirks mode should come before that. Also it would help to say what you are observing and what is off to your eye. To mine it looks identical in IE.

Comment: Check page in IE 7, 8, 9

Comment: Note: I removed the PHP Contact Form from the question again because a) It belongs in another, separate question and b) You have provided no code for it so we cannot help.

Comment: hey @elclanrs thanks.. the link you gave solved my problem.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add a proper document type at the start of your document. IE is rendering document in Quirk Mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

In IE 10 your page is rendering correctly, IE 9, 8, 7 having issue. Apply above fix and it will solve the problem.

For your second problem refer to following

[Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25)

Comment: Rendering is nearly identical with Quirks or Standards mode, so this is more general advice than an answer to their question.

Comment: @Јοеу Please read the following article (side note). http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

It may be IE transparency issue on style.css-(ul.accordion li .bgDescription). Refer http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/

and try to change transparency code or write seperate code for ie browser transparency. Hope it helps.