# PHP - mailer error : fail to connect to mailserver

Tags: php, html, email, smtp, localhost

I'm somewhat new to php and html coding and is wondering why I have this error.
The mail is suppose to automatically send me information on what my customers bought; quantity and amount via email. However I'm constantly having this problem when I test run.

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\process.php on line 39
    $myusername=$_SESSION['username'];
    $sql="SELECT email FROM member WHERE username='$myusername'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $from = $result;
    $subject = $myusername . "'s Purchases of ". $_SESSION['amount'] ." of XXXX.";
    $message = $_SESSION["payamount"] . "via CHEQUE/Cash on Collection.";
    $mail = mail("okay1@gmail.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
```

Comment: Exactly how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

View this thread's answer to know how to configure your smtp server

[Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25)

Answer (score 0):

you can use phpmailer to send emial
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php

Comment: that thousand lines of code... how do i even use it?