# Error in using mail function?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

Here `$msg` and `$subject` are the variables getting values from the  form. When the submit button is clicked, `mail()` function is to be called.

But there is a warning displayed:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "`" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in 
>   D:\wamp\www\abhishek\wp-content\themes\abhishek\career.php on line
>   18.

Here is my code:

```
$msg=$_POST['msg'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
mail('email@example.com',$subject,$msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to setup a mail server locally on your machine.The mail function needs SMTP servers for sending out the mails.So you would need to mention the smtp port and smtp host on the `php.ini` file.

.Please have a look at a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25)

Answer (score -2):

This is just an example, change values......

```
$header = "From: contact@".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]."\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$recipient = "abhijain.cse@gmail.com"
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

    $body='<table width="90%" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td><b>Name:</b></td> <td>'.$name.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Email:</b></td> <td>'.$email.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Message:</b></td> <td>'.$message.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></table>';

    $res=@mail($recipient,$subject,$body,$header);
```

Comment: The user is getting a message saying `Failed to connect to mailserver`. The issue is a connection problem, and this answer doesn't deal with that at all.