# how to check smtp connected or not using php. i am newbie to php

Tags: php, smtp, server

```
include("../confi.php");
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//echo $select_smtp="SELECT * FROM `smtp_connection`";
$select_smtp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `smtp_connection` WHERE `status`=1",$database);
while($result_select = mysql_fetch_array($select_smtp))
{

    $hostname= $result_select['host_name'];
    $username= $result_select['user_name'];
    $userpass= $result_select['user_pass'];
    $status= $result_select['status'];
    $time= $result_select['check_time'];
    $port="25/pop3";
    $mbox = imap_open( "{".$hostname.":".$port."/novalidate-cert}" , $username, $userpass);

    if ($mbox) {
        echo "connected";
        imap_close($mbox);
    } else {
        echo "not connected :<br>" . imap_last_error();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25)

Comment: i cant find actual error. all smtp server are connected but its not shown in code. output is as follow: IP Not connected : COMPUTER-NAME.npet.in ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 8.60-- ready at 06/30/15 22:25:54 @Sagar

Comment: can sm1 plz post appropriate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question really is "how to check smtp connected or not", then the answer is: you did great!

The documentation of [imap_open()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imap-open.php) clearly states that the function returns either a resource or `FALSE` in case of a failure. So your conditional `if ($mbox)` reliably checks if the connection was successful.

You could make the condition more readable and explicit though: `if (FALSE === $mbox)`

Comment: but smtp or hostname is connected and i want to show that. but my code alwys display ip not connected when its working

Comment: As said: `imap_open()` reports that the connection failed if `$mbox` resolves to `FALSE` in the condition. Why do you think it succeeded? How do you tell?

Comment: can u please give me a solution for this?? its my assesment

Comment: Sorry, no, I cannot give you a solution, since I do not see an issue here to be solved. I cannot say why your connection attempts fail.

Comment: i am trying from 2 dys but ddnt fine any gud result.

Comment: Then maybe you ask the wrong question? you did not answer to my question two comments above...

Comment: No idea what that is meat to say, sorry.

Comment: i just want to check smtp health. now i can say that.

Comment: Still no answer to my question above. Instead you through code at me. Sorry, I am out.

Comment: should i use socket or smthng??