# Concurrent trigger of mails in PHP

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I was trying to send mails concretely using php(5.6.21), xampp(3.2.2) 'mail()'. I am getting the below error. I tired in all possible ways and could find out the root cause.

```
PHP Warning:  mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;smtp.tecnotree.com&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\1.php on line 11, referer:abc.com/test/1.php
```

Please help me on the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25)

Comment: use phpmailer, it will make more easier to send mail from localhost

Comment: ours is not local system problem, we are doing this in a windows server and we have set up the STMP also. We are getting this error only with the attached Apache, php versions. When we tried with other xampp versions it worked fine. Is there anything we are missing to configure in xampp 3.2.2 version for sending mails