# Warninmail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port"

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying to access my php application from another computer within LAN . But unable send mail . can anyone help me with the configuration settings and steps to fix it . I am getting below error . but i was able send mail in localhost but not working while hosing

this my link for hosting http://192.45.199.25:8080/Qc/login.php

Comment: Well sounds like there is no SMTP server in the host where you're trying to connect to.

Comment: Thanks . How can i fix it .?

Comment: Probably by connecting to an existing server in some other host. Of course it can be installed to that server too, but we can't really here know what your environment is like.

Comment: Hi , I have fixed it by giving the IP adrees instead localhost and givent the mail path in php.ini its working fine now . Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25)