# Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmailer

I am using the contact form for sending the mails on my system but am getting this errors:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port
>   25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use
>   ini_set() in D:\xampp\htdocs\sample-emailer\samplemail.php on line 32

Error sending email!

My **php.ini**

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from =you@yoursite.com
```

How to solve this?

Comment: You have to have SMTP configured to use it in your mail() function. Take a look at this answer for more details on configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55008494/1141944

Comment: Hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25

Comment: @Udhav Sarvaiya  am using windows8 how to enable the smtp server