# Getting an error in my mail php, not sure how to correct it

Tags: php

I'm running a localhost server to test my mail php code, but I'm getting this error `Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Users\User\Desktop\html\contact.php on line 29`, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can anyone help me?

This is my php code that doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php

if($_POST) {
    $visitor_name = "";
    $visitor_email = "";
    $email_title = "";
    $concerned_department = "";
    $visitor_message = "";

    if(isset($_POST['visitor_name'])) {
        $visitor_name = filter_var($_POST['visitor_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['visitor_email'])) {
        $visitor_email = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d"), '', $_POST['visitor_email']);
        $visitor_email = filter_var($visitor_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['email_title'])) {
        $email_title = filter_var($_POST['email_title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
        $recipient = "mygmail@gmail.com";
    }

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"
    .'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n"
    .'From: ' . $visitor_email . "\r\n";

    if(mail($recipient, $email_title, $visitor_message, $headers)) {
        echo "<p>Thank you for contacting us</p>";
    } else {
        echo '<p>We're sorry, but your message didn't go through</p>';
    }

    {
    echo '<p>Something went wrong</p>';
}

?>
```

Comment: I highly suggest you to use `PHPMailer` ( https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer ) or `swiftmailer`

Comment: mail() wont work on localserver, you don't have a mail server installed

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25 Please search your error in site first